# Github API: How to sort public repositories by count of stars?

Tags: github-api

I am looking for api on github that could give me a count of stars for repositories

I know about `/repositories` which give me public repositories but I don't know how to get count of stars of repository.

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `/repositories` get all the public repositories. In response you would get name of the owner and also repository name, then use `Get` on each of those repositories. In the response of for each of those repositories, field `stargazers_count` will give you number of stars each repository has.

Some sample python code:

```
import requests
public_repos = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repositories').json()

for repo in public_repos:
    repo_name = repo['name']
    owner = repo['owner']['login']  
    repo_info = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/'+owner+'/'+repo_name)
    stars = repo_info.json()['stargazers_count']
    print(repo_name, stars)
```

The output is:

```
grit 1874
merb-core 401
rubinius 2176
god 1592
jsawesome 12
```

Have a look at [/repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-public-repositories) and [Get](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get)

Comment: it would easily get up to the rate limiting

Comment: @Longerian you could just easily pass access token though.

Comment: @RoastBiter isn't it still very limited?

Comment: use caching on those API requests. That caching coupled with 5k per hour limit should be good.