# Stargazer count for a particular repo

Tags: github-api

I am looking for a way to get star count for a given repository. All I found is to get all repositories in the organization and get the count for all repositories. Is there a way to get star count for a given repository url?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806666/github-api-how-to-sort-public-repositories-by-count-of-stars

Comment: this example requests all the repos. I am looking for count for only one single given repo.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have the following repo:

```
https://github.com/ammadanwer/udacityp5
```

You can get its information from github api using the url

```
https://api.github.com/repos/ammadanwer/udacityp5
```

What you are looking for can be found as `stargazers_count`

Comment: It seems there is a limit of 6 for calling the api. How can I pass that limit?

Comment: You can generate a personal access token from you own github account here: https://github.com/settings/tokens
give it the scope of "public_repo" and use that in the header while making the API request like "Authorization: token GITHUB_TOKEN"`. This should increase the daily limit to 5000.